# Can't make Safenet PKI client "find" my etoken (12.04 LTS)

Tags: hardware, signature

Well, I need to use the Etoken to digitally sign invoices in my country for my company. I have installed Safenet 8.1 software, and I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04. The PKI client (from Safenet) can't find the etoken.

I did a `lsusb -v`:

```
    Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0529:0600 Aladdin Knowledge Systems eToken Pro 64k (4.2)
    Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
    Device Descriptor:
      bLength                18
      bDescriptorType         1
      bcdUSB               1.10
      bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
      bDeviceSubClass         0 
      bDeviceProtocol         0 
      bMaxPacketSize0        64
      idVendor           0x0529 Aladdin Knowledge Systems
      idProduct          0x0600 eToken Pro 64k (4.2)
      bcdDevice            1.00
      iManufacturer           1 
      iProduct                2 
      iSerial                 0 
      bNumConfigurations      1
      Configuration Descriptor:
        bLength                 9
        bDescriptorType         2
        wTotalLength           20
        bNumInterfaces          1
        bConfigurationValue     1
        iConfiguration          0 
        bmAttributes         0x80
          (Bus Powered)
        MaxPower              100mA
        Interface Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType         4
          bInterfaceNumber        0
          bAlternateSetting       0
          bNumEndpoints           0
          bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
          bInterfaceSubClass      0 
          bInterfaceProtocol      0 
          iInterface              0 
          ** UNRECOGNIZED:  02 ff
```

My system is updated, all libs for authentication installed (I believe).

I did a major research and could not find a solution to this neither on the forums or Ask Ubuntu.I'm starting with Ubuntu, can do a thing or two, but this is something I can't figure out.

Could someone point me what could be wrong? I belive that the:

```
  **Unrecognized: 02ff
```

Is the main part of the problem.

(EDIT) `pcsc-scan` can't find the etoken, neither `opensc-tools -l -n`. Only when i do a `lsusb`.

(EDIT2)

```
felipe@Monstro:~$ sudo openct-tool list 
      0 Aladdin eToken PRO 64k
```

Openct can detect it...but I don't know how to use this info. Reinstalled `'pcsc-lite'` with `'libusb'` and the following config:

```
'./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --
localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --enable-daemon --
enable-libusb --disable-libhal --enable-
usbdropdir=/usr/lib64/pcsc/drivers'
```

Comment: I have opensc installed, as have pkcs11-helper. I digged deep into google to find a solution, but I'm still far from it.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, however it's worthy a shot. In my understanding it's just the opposite. I work here with ikey2032 and etoken pro 72k. You only disable libhal and enable libusb to work with ikey. I do use ubuntu 12.04 too, 32bit and 64bit. I just do a clean instalation via dpkg, resolve all dependencies (pcsc and libhal) and it works fine for etoken. I could never make it work with ikey.

Hope it helps
Erick

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem and i was solved that. 
I was remove every packages was i used to fing my eToken (ex p11-kit, pcscd,opensc openct etc) after that i was install SafNet pki driver for eToken and required packages (pcscd). 
In file
 */etc/gnutls/pkcs11.conf*
   i was add line

```
load=/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so
```

after this operation i p11tool i could see my eToken

I hope that will be helpful for somone

Comment: Where could you download the SafeNet pki driver?